# export to excel maatwebsite

Tags: excel, laravel, export, laravel-5.8

I trying to export file in the database into excel using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel. it has no error but only blank page i did. i follow the step tutorial, 
ive got config/excel.php, app/Export/UserExport.php
i've add route

```
Route::get('/backend/user/export', [
    'uses' =>'Backend\UserController@export', 
    'as' => 'backend.user.export']);
```

here is my controller

```
   public function export()
    {
        return Excel::download(new UserExport, 'user.xlsx');
    }
```

and this is my export button

```
<a href="{{ route('backend.user.export') }}">
    <button class="dt-button buttons-html5 btn bg-teal-400 position-left" type="button" style="float: right;">
       <span>Export to Excel <i class=" icon-file-excel position-right"></i></span>
    </button>
</a>
```

UserExport.php

```
use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class UserExport implements FromCollection
{

    public function collection()
    {
        return User::all();

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code behind UserExport?

Comment: what code? @Andreasfi

Comment: What version of Maatwebsite\Excel are you using?

Comment: 3.1? i just following this step https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html. i'm using laravel 5.8 @Andreasfi

Comment: i use resource controller is that matter? but i use method get in the route

Comment: Everything looks all right. Could you check you have data in the database just to be sure? It is also possible that you environment causes the problem (installed OS, php version etc). Also try to change the extension to .csv

Comment: hei @Andreasfi thanks for your quick response, the problem was solved. ive change the route name '/backend/user/export' to 'user-export'. i dont know if route name can be a problem. thanks btw

Comment: Oh I see. Yes because your third parameter (export) is dynamic (you pass the user.id there). Another solution is to move your export route above the route with the dynamic parameter (so that /backend/user/export is before /backend/user/{user}).